# Outlook 2013 rule to copy email body to clipboard

Tags: vba, email, outlook, rule

Using an e-mail rule to trigger a VBA script, is it possible to send the body of an email to the clipboard?  I've found this [method](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/paste-clipboard-contents-vba/) but it doesn't appear to work.

```
Sub SaveToClipboard(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim Explorer As Outlook.Explorer
Dim oitem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oData As MSForms.DataObject


Set Explorer = Application.ActiveExplorer

If Explorer.Selection.Count Then

    Set CurrentItem = Explorer.Selection(1)
    Set oitem = CurrentItem

    oData = oitem.Body  
    oData.PutInClipboard

    'Using this to test the output
    MsgBox oData

End If
End Sub
```

And following that, how would I search for a line in the body of the email starting with "Info:" and only copy that line to the clipboard?

Comment: Only one question per thread. First search for something like "vba structured text" and start a new question, if necessary, after you put together some code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing important pieces described in the samples on that site.

As well use the mailitem passed in (itm As mailItem).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SaveToClipboard_test()

    Dim curritem As Object
    Set curritem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
    If TypeOf curritem Is mailItem Then SaveToClipboard curritem

ExitRoutine:
    Set curritem = Nothing

End Sub


Sub SaveToClipboard(itm As mailItem)

    Dim oData As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim strPaste As Variant

    Set oData = New MSForms.DataObject
    oData.SetText itm.body
    oData.PutInClipboard

    oData.GetFromClipboard
    strPaste = oData.GetText

    strPaste = Left(strPaste, 1024)
    MsgBox strPaste

ExitRoutine:
    Set oData = Nothing

End Sub
```